# System.Delegate System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

As best as I can tell, this error has occurred in the past when Ninject is and the target for the site package are 4.x and do not match each other. I have checked on my machine and they match - both are 4.0.

I did just spend some time updating all the Nu-Get packages in my project. Prior to that, this error did not occur.

How can I eliminate this error?

Here is my full error output:

```
enter code here
```

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Method not found: 'System.Delegate System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type)'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Delegate System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type)'.

```
Source Error: 


Line 29:             DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
Line 30:             DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
Line 31:             bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
Line 32:         }
Line 33: 


Source File: C:\My Documents\Alcon_DEV\SecurityMasterData\Dev\Alcon.SecurityMasterData.WebUI\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs    Line: 31 

Stack Trace: 


[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Delegate System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type)'.]
   Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.Create(ConstructorInfo constructor) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Injection\DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.cs:48
   Ninject.Planning.Strategies.ConstructorReflectionStrategy.Execute(IPlan plan) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Strategies\ConstructorReflectionStrategy.cs:67
   Ninject.Planning.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateNewPlan>b__0(IPlanningStrategy s) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Planner.cs:109
   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:32
   Ninject.Planning.Planner.CreateNewPlan(Type type) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Planner.cs:109
   Ninject.Planning.Planner.GetPlan(Type type) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Planner.cs:71
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:77
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Resolve>b__c(IBinding binding) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:386
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +151
   System.Linq.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext() +92
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +196
   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:37
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.CreateDependencyResolver() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.cs:83
   Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.Start() in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin.cs:54
   Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.<Initialize>b__0(INinjectHttpApplicationPlugin c) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\Bootstrapper.cs:52
   Ninject.Infrastructure.Language.ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.Map(IEnumerable`1 series, Action`1 action) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Language\ExtensionsForIEnumerableOfT.cs:32
   Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(Func`1 createKernelCallback) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Ninject.Web.Common\src\Ninject.Web.Common\Bootstrapper.cs:52
   Alcon.SecurityMasterData.WebUI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start() in C:\My Documents\Alcon_DEV\SecurityMasterData\Dev\Alcon.SecurityMasterData.WebUI\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs:31

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +72
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +335
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +19
   WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +241
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +611
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunPreStartMethods(Boolean designerMode) +50
   WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +80

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +423
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +306
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +591

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9010364
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256
```

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: It looks like this function only exists in 4.5. So event though the properties for this version say 4.0.3, it is targeting 4.5?

Comment: I recopied Ninject, Ninject MVC, and Ninject ASP from another location.

For whatever reason, it was pulling the 4.5 lib.

Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That method not exists in .net 4.5 - before then, Delegate.CreateDelegate should be used instead. It sounds to me like maybe NInject is incorrectly using that method in a 4.0 nuget package, in which case you should report that as a bug in NInject.

The first thing to do is to check you are using the correct version of the dll, i.e. specifically a 4.0 build.

After that, one of:

- roll back to an earlier NInject version
- upgrade your .net framework version
- download the code, fix it, and submit a patch

Comment: Please note my comment above. Indeed the issue was 4.5 vs 4.0.